# Treat Type Parameter As A Numeric Using Implicits

Tags: scala

I'm having trouble with the following polymorphic function definition:

```
scala> def foo[A](x : A, y : A)(implicit o : A => Numeric[A]) : A = x + y
<console>:7: error: type mismatch;
 found   : A
 required: String
       def foo[A](x : A, y : A)(implicit o : A => Numeric[A]) : A = x + y
```

I would like to specify that the type parameter `A` can be used as a `Numeric` but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Numeric[A]` is typically a single instance, that gives access to arithmetic operations on the type `A`. It will contains `def plus(x: A, y: A): A`, rather than `def add(x: A): A`, which would have some `this` of type A.

It is akin to java's `Comparator` (or scala's `Ordering`) which has a `Compare(T o1, T o2)`, rather than to java `Comparable` (scala's `Ordered`) which has a `CompareTo(T other)`. Such types, with implicitly available singleton implementations, are typically called typeclasses, after a closely related feature in the Haskell language.

So you don't want to convert `A` to `Numeric[A]`, you just want a `Numeric[A]`. 
Your signature should be

```
def foo[A](x: A, y: A)(implicit numeric: Numeric[A])
```

There is a shortcut for that, which is

```
def foo[A: Numeric](x: A, y: A)
```

In method `foo`, you can do `numeric.plus(x,y)`, but if you `import scala.math.Numeric._`, you get some magic and the much more convenient `x + y`.

---

Regarding the question in comment :  has there been a language change since Programming in scala (which is on v 2.8) ?

The syntax `[A: Numeric]`, called a `context bound`, has been introduced late in the language, I'm not 100% sure, but I believe it was not available in 2.8. But this is just a shortcut for an `implicit Numeric[A]` argument, which was possible in 2.8 (`Numeric` was available -just introduced actually- in 2.8), and should have been used as shown above at the time. Except for that, there was no language change.

However, in the early times of scala, it was more common to use "views", meaning implicit conversions, rather than typeclasses, that is to use types such as `Comparable`/`Ordered`, rather than `Comparator`/`Ordering`/`Numeric`.

For such types, you would typically use an upper bound `A <: Ordered[A]`. However, this may be a bit too restrictive as it will works only if the implementor had the foresight to implement `Ordered`. You can get around that but requiring that `A` may be converted to an Ordered[A], so `implicit A => Ordered[A]`.

There used to be a shortcut for that, `[A <% Ordered[A]]`, called a *view bound*. However, it has been deprecated, and while views are still possible (`implicit A => Ordered[A]`), typeclasses are much preferred. There are a lot of reasons for that, e.g.:

- having conversion functions in the implicit scope will act as implicit casts and are quite dangerous
- typeclasses are more powerful. For instance, you can have an instance of  `Numeric[A]` even when you have no instances of `A` around, and so get the `zero` of type `A`. if you call `sum` on a list and the list is empty, the `Numeric` is still available and you can get the `zero`. if `Numeric` was something implemented by `A`, even if it made `zero` available, you would have no instance to call it on. Another example, a typeclass may be used as a factory, again when you have no instance of the constructed type (yet), as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28886370/754787).

To quote Martin Odersky ([discussing deprecation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-sips/wP6dL8nIAQs)):

> context bounds are essentially the replacement of view bounds. It's
>   what we should have done from the start, but we did not know better
>   back then

Comment: Thanks. Have Typesafe changed the syntax for implicits as I mimicked a code snippet from the Programming in Scala book which defined a function as I have done in my post.

Comment: answered in the reply above

Answer (score 2):

The two changes you need is that, *first* the `implicit` should not be a function from `A` to `Numeric[A]`, but simply `Numeric[A]`, and *second* you need to import `Numeric.Implicits` to get the implicit `Ops` that enable `+`.

```
import scala.math.Numeric.Implicits._

def foo[A](x : A, y : A)(implicit num: Numeric[A]) : A = x + y
```

Without the import you'd have to write it as:

```
def foo[A](x : A, y : A)(implicit num: Numeric[A]) : A = num.plus(x,y)
```